# Jquery css place a element just right to an top/bottom to a an another element

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code :
[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/pUmCz/4/)

How do i place an element just right to the element top or bottom of it regarding to the postion to the browser.
I know there are many plugins available for this named context menus but there is something i cant do with them

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should encode ">" with "&gt;".

Comment: What do you want an element to appear beside? You never told us what "it" is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/pUmCz/8/

You can then adjust the position of the shown elements by using the CSS `top` or `bottom` properties

Comment: sorry, something weird happened there.